# I appear to have 500 error page and no 404 error page, why?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to create custom 500 and 404 error pages

here's my .htaccess page:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry, this page was not found"
ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, something went wrong, try again later"
```

here's a 404 page http://example.com/cats - not a page (but it's showing as a 500)

and this one should be a 500 http://example.com/dogs - a page (because the query returned is blank) but it's not an error message at all - guessing this should be a 500 anyway, i would like it to be

It appears to always show 500 and no 404, but I can't figure out how to stop/fix it, any ideas???

Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a 500 will only be thrown if there is an exception thrown by php, not by logical errors. a select query returning a blank result isn't considered to be an error by php as sometimes queries will return a blank result as part of the legitimate flow of the code.

with regards to getting a 500 instead of a 400, it appears here http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess2.shtml that you should be forwarding to a page rather than trying to pass in a string. set up a page that you want to be displayed and then put the url in your htaccess

like so:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/serverr.html
```

Comment: no change, sadly (using this now: ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/505.html)

Comment: I'm not an expert on .htaccess, but it's possible that some of your fancy rewriting is interfering with the process, try commenting out all the rewriting and try throw a 404

Comment: "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." indicates to me it could be just a basic syntax error in the .htaccess as well